# Visual Studio Code saves file as root ownership when not intended

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not sure if this is a bug or update/user setting change where on file save, it would change the file ownership to root, causing me to having to chown back to my own local user. Has anyone else experienced this? I noticed it only does it for Visual Studios so far.

Comment: You have a very messed up system if a user can create arbitrary files owned by root. Are you possibly starting Visual Studios using `sudo`?

Comment: I am starting as user, and it is saving the file as root ownership

Comment: I really see only three options. (1) `sudo` or `gksu` is involved somewhere. Check your sudo logs to make sure it's not being invoked. (2) `code` has been installed setuid. `ls -l $(which code)` will show this. (3) Your system has been compromised.

Comment: for point (2) I have lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jun  3 18:58 /usr/bin/code -> /usr/share/code/bin/code

this seems wrong, I should chown it back to user:user correct?

Comment: The owner and permissions of the symlink really don't matter. You need to look at the perms on `/usr/share/code/bin/code`.

Comment: It was owned by root:root. I think during an update it messed with the settings. Not too sure why the case was I have changed that back to user:user. You have been so helpful!